# How do I change PATH so that bash shell locates gcc from a different directory?

Tags: bash, shell, gcc

I'm running macOS Mojave (10.14.6) and carried out the following instructions:
[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9p00.png)
[Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zvqs.png)
[Page 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8cdG.png)

I've followed the instructions without any problems so far but when I enter "type gcc" into the terminal like the book asks on page 3, I get the following:

```
$ type gcc
gcc is /usr/bin/gcc
```

The book makes it clear that if the the bash shell is locating gcc from a different directory, the PATH is not set correctly. So how do I fix the PATH so that the bash shell locates gcc at the desired directory (“/opt/gcc-arm/bin/gcc”)?

[Page 3 (Continued)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my1cL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mentioned in step 10 of your own instructions:

> 10. Now, exit root and return to your developer session. In that session, add the compiler’s bin directory to your PATH:
>
>     `$ export PATH="/opt/gcc-arm/bin:$PATH"`

Note that your instructions also show a different name for the compiler – instead of "gcc", it is named "arm-none-eabi-gcc". (The last page says that if you obtain the compiler *from other sources*, it may be named just "gcc".)

So try `type arm-none-eabi-gcc` first. If the above change doesn't work, you should actually *look inside* /opt/gcc-arm/bin and check what executables are present.

Finally, if you're using bash, the `type` command will use its internal cache of previously found paths; you might need to run `hash -r` to clear this cache.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I had tried everything you suggested already (good to know I was on the right track!) - except for the hash -r command. Tried everything again after the cache was cleared and still got "gcc is /usr/bin/gcc". I checked inside /opt/gcc-arm/bin and found arm-none-eabi-gcc but not gcc. The instructions actually tell you to also enter "type arm-none-eabi-gcc" later (see "Page 3 (Continued)" from my recent edit). So why would the instructions ask me to enter "type gcc" if the commands from the previous instructions never created gcc in the /opt/gcc-arm/bin folder?

Comment: Never mind, I reread the instructions. It clearly says “If you see the file name gcc instead of arm-none-eabi-gcc, you’ll need to invoke it as simply gcc. In this case ....” Apologies for wasting time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in home directory of your user using .bash_profile file. 
Add line `export PATH=$PATH:/<path_to_your_gcc>`

Hope it will help.